# In PHP number with 19 digit changes in to exponential number

Tags: php

In PHP i have define a variable with 19 digit long number and then print it. But it changes into exponential NUmber which is not acceptable in API Use. I need it as NUMBER. Here is an example of Problem.

```
$a = 1435483000000072013;
echo $a;
```

adn it returns `1.4354830000001E+18`

Also, I have tried following function but it return wrong number

```
function output($x) {
    $f = sprintf('%0.08f', $x);
    $f = rtrim($f,'0');
    $f = rtrim($f,'.');
    return $f;
} 
echo output(1435483000000072013);
```

this returns me `1435483000000071936` Number changes

So what is solution for this??

Comment: If the number is too large, it becomes a float and precision is lost. Why not declare it as a string?

Answer (score 1):

Champ, PHP doesn't have strictly typed variables, but it still has to decide whether your number is an int, a float or a double when it stores the information. And your number is larger than INT_MAX, so it's not going to fit into an integer format. That means the system has to bump it up to at least a float, which is where you're getting the exponential format from.

See NoGray's solution for how to fix it. Your number is still being stored, it's just being represented differently because your number is too big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use number_format with an empty string for the thousands separator
e.g.

```
$a = 1435483000000072013;
echo number_format($a, 0, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 1.435483000000072013;
printf("%.18f",$a);
```